Bad Request 400 status
url = "/IPM/KPI/Add"; input = new FormData($('#frmKPI').get(0)) ;

PostAjax: function (isForm, url, input, divErrID, btnID, isSuccessFunction, isFailedFunction, NoModalAlert, isAsync)
{
    var contentType = isForm ? false : "application/json;";
    var processData = isForm ? false : true;

    $(btnID).prop("disabled", true);
    Loading(true);
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: input,
        async: isAsync == null || isAsync == undefined ? false : isAsync,
        dataType: "json",
        headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
        contentType: contentType,
        processData: processData,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.IsSuccess) {
                if (isSuccessFunction != null)
                    isSuccessFunction(data);
    
                if (!NoModalAlert)
                    ModalAlert(MODAL_HEADER, data.Result);
    
                $(divErrID).html("");
            } else {
                var msg = "";
                if (data.IsListResult == true) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.Result.length; i++) {
                        msg += data.Result[i] + "<br />";
                    }
                } else {
                    msg += data.Result;
                }
                ModalAlert(MODAL_HEADER, msg);
                if (isFailedFunction != null)
                    isFailedFunction();
            }
            $(btnID).prop("disabled", false);
            Loading(false);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("AJAX Error:", jqXHR.status, jqXHR.statusText);
            console.log("Response Text:", jqXHR.responseText);
            if (isFailedFunction != null)
                isFailedFunction();
            Loading(false);
            $(btnID).prop("disabled", false);
            ModalAlert(MODAL_HEADER, jqXHR.responseText);
        },
    });

}

please help, I have tried making the data convert to stringify but it does not work. basically I'm working a .net core razor web-api, and I'm trying to post a form when I save it and should go to my Add.cshtml.cs (handler = OnPostAsync)

Please explain/ask an actual question on your one issue here and not just say "I tried". HTML would help us help you better here; perhaps use the <> button to create a working snippet of you code.  Don't forget to format all your code as code for clarity

Note that data: input, input is not defined here, nor is url

The error tells you that the browser does not accept the data you are sending. We however don't know what your server is accepting for data, nor what you are actually sending. We need a [mcve] in order to be able to help you.

hi sorry I'm new to this, I updated my question. I hope you can help me

Your question doesn't even contain a question.

If you want to call the webapi method in the Add.cshtml.cs, we need to modify the URL, for example https://your_sitename.com/Add?handler=methodname.
My test code in Index.cshtml.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace WebApplication2.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

        public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {

        }
        public IActionResult OnGetApi()
        {
            var data = new { Message = "Hello from API" };
            return new JsonResult(data);
        }
        public IActionResult OnPostAApi()
        {
            var data = new { Message = "Hello from API" };
            return new JsonResult(data);
        }
    }
}

Test result for Get Request(method name is Api)

Test result for Post Request(method name is AApi)



Thank you this is another way of solving it. The real issue in my code lies in modelstate, wherein the data types of my model and the data types I'm passing in the ajax are different. Additionally, I have discovered that it is unnecessary to add handler name when posting, the .net core will automatically look the handler name OnPostAync for you.
